# Position image and keep fluid with text

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it where this picture of a Pen is behind the "Create" text and positioned to the left. At full size it looks fine, but when you adjust the screen size it loses its positioning. How can I make it responsive so when I adjust the screen size it stays with the "Create" texts in front of it?[Example](https://promises.kommigraphics.com/), I want to make it look like this site where the image is positioned behind the text.

```css
#home_nav {
  background-color: #5680E9;
}
a{
  color:#ffffff;
}
.btn{color:#ffffff;}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
.text-right {
  position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
right: 16px;
}
```

```html
      <!--Where the buttons are located-->
      <div class="container-fluid" id="home_nav">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div style="position:relative;">
          <img src="/STEMuli_Website/img/pen.png" alt="Pen" style="width:40%;position:absolute; left:-20px; bottom:-100px"></img></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><div class="display-2 home_text text-right ">Create</div></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="display-2 home_text"><a href="/STEMuli_Website/HTML_Pages/Explore.html">Explore</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-2 home_text"><a href="#">Your Library</a></div>
      </div>
      <!--RSS feed here-->
      <div class="col-8">
        <div class="feedgrabbr_widget" id="fgid_15f3fc7e5ddb0c39637a55949"></div>
        <script>
          if (typeof(fg_widgets) === "undefined") fg_widgets = new Array();
          fg_widgets.push("fgid_15f3fc7e5ddb0c39637a55949");
        </script>
        <script async src="https://www.feedgrabbr.com/widget/fgwidget.js"></script>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish; I keep wondering why you're not placing your icon in with the button ala https://www.bootply.com/ptUCpIjxYJ ... Side note: `</img>` is not a real tag.

Comment: @RobertC , I want to accomplish something similar to this website [link](https://promises.kommigraphics.com/). How those images are positioned behind texts. And thanks on the </img> lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you're using uses the property `z-index`. Basically it positions html elements in 3-d. elements with higher z-indices are on top of ones with lower z-indices. Note in my example how the blue div is completely on top of the red div. change the z-index to toggle that.

```
.one{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:20;
}

.two{
    position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
    z-index:10;
}

<div class="one">
some content goes here.
</div>

<div class="two">
some content goes here.

</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/rkvgaa77/6/)